# R command not working for google colab , provided the command below with error

Tags: r

COMMAND:

```
install.packages('animation', repos = 'https://xran.yihui.org')
```

ERROR:

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

Warning message:
“dependency ‘magick’ is not available”
Warning message in install.packages("animation", repos = "https://xran.yihui.org"):
“installation of package ‘animation’ had non-zero exit status”
```

Comment: Did you try installing from cran?

Comment: can you please specify how i can do so?

Answer (score 1):

```
system('add-apt-repository -y ppa:cran/imagemagick')
system('apt-get update')
system("apt-get install libmagick++-dev")
install.packages("magick")
```

this command workout for me after execution this command run the install command again

```
install.packages('animation', repos = 'https://xran.yihui.org')
```